# Leafletjs show my location marker instead of hardcoded location

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet, maps

I am trying out Leaflet.js and I have a map with a marker like this:

```
var marker = new L.marker([5.897818, -1.120009],{
    draggable: true,
    autoPan: true
}).addTo(mymap);
```

This is showing ok but I want it to appear on my current location instead of the above hardcoded location.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to tap into the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) and use the results of that to create a marker.

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  const { coords: { latitude, longitude }} = position;
  var marker = new L.marker([latitude, longitude], {
    draggable: true,
    autoPan: true
  }).addTo(mymap);

  console.log(marker);
})
```

There's some issue using the API with Stackoverflow, so here's a link to a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgtpaqe2/).

Comment: Its asked my for permission for the geolocation but the the marker doesn't appear..Does it not work when you open the html page on your computer on you browser locally?

Comment: Ah okay I see what it is. I made this awhile ago so there's an embedded API key in there. If you go to [MapBox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-tokens-api/) you can create your own API key. After you get one, just update the part of the script where it's setting the tile layer, and replace everything after `access_token` with your own key.

Comment: Ok, ive created an account and changed the access token but still no pointer appearing. I am using chrome and opening the html files by double-clicking on the file which is on my desktop. Do I need to host this page online for it to show the geolocation marker?

Comment: I would add some logging within the callback for `getCurrentPosition` to verify it's getting the position information. Separately, are you able to get this to work within JSFiddle or some hosted environment?

Comment: The console logs below are returning nothing: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  const { coords: { latitude, longitude }} = position;
  var marker = new L.marker([latitude, longitude], {
    draggable: true,
    autoPan: true
  }).addTo(mymap);

  console.log(`${latitude}-${longitude}`);
  console.log(marker);
})

Comment: No geolocation marker is appearing at all. What browser are you using?